# Defining Temporary Object For Class Methods

Tags: c#, class

I have a public class called "HotelUtilities" that contains alot of methods. What is the best way to implement a TEMPORARY object that can be shared among the HotelUtilities methods? (I don't want the object to be accessed OUTSIDE the main HotelUtilities class.) Is it best practice to use a struct, another class or something else for Visitor? For example, take a look at "Visitor", the TEMPORARY object...

```
namespace Utilities
{
    public static class HotelUtilities
    {
        public class TempVisitor
        {
            internal Guid UserId;
            internal string EmailAddress;
            internal string FirstName;
            internal string LastName;
            internal integer CountryCode;
        }

        public static List<TempVisitor> GetForeignVisitors()
        {
```

The Visitor object is only TEMPORARY and will only be used/shared by various methods in the HotelUtilities class. I don't want it to be used outside of HotelUtilities.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably make the class `private`.

Comment: For more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_class_data_pattern

Comment: @John - if i make it private I get an "inconsistent accessibility" error when I try to use it in List<TempVisitor>.

Comment: @WebDevGuy you specifically stated that the class should only be accessible within HotelUtilities. The reason you're getting that message is because you're returning it via a public method, which seems to conflict with what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question, you can define an empty class or interface that is used in your public methods. Have a private class that extends the empty class with the properties/fields you want, and cast them.

```
public static class HotelUtilities
{
    public interface ITempVisitor
    {
    }

    private class HiddenTempVisitor : ITempVisitor
    {
       internal Guid UserId;
    }

    public static List<ITempVisitor> GetTempVisitors()
    {
        return new List<ITempVisitor>() { new HiddenTempVisitor { UserId = Guid.NewGuid } };
    }

    public static void UseTempVisitors(List<ITempVisitor> visitors)
    {
        foreach (HiddenTempVisitor visitor in visitors)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(visitor.UserId);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this really seems like a code smell to me. In fact, I consider it quite horrible. Consider if someone else creates their own class that extends ITempVisitor, then UseTempVisitors will crash with an invalid cast exception.

Another possibility is to change your return type to `object`, and when you need to use it, the method accepts an object and casts it to a List. That way it doesn't matter if TempVisitor is private, since it won't be part of any public interface. But it's still pretty awful since the compiler won't give errors when data types other than List are passed in.

Since what you're trying to do doesn't fit nicely with OO design, it probably means that your code can be redesigned be work more naturally. In a non-static class you can make your TempVisitor class private and keep the list of TempVisitors in a private field. To make the code more understandable, you'll probably want to extract the methods that use the TempVisitor into a new class with a more meaningful name, but some people consider utility/helper classes an anti-pattern, so it's probably good to do that anyway.

```
public class EventGuestEmailer
{
    private class GuestInfo
    {
        public Guid GuestId;
        public string EmailAddress;
    }

    private List<GuestInfo> _guests;
    private IDataAccess _dataStore;
    private IEmailSender _emailer;

   public EventGuestEmailer(IDataAccess dataStore, IEmailSender emailer)
   {
       _dataStore = dataStore;
       _emailer = emailer;
   }

   public void GetGuestsAtEvent(int eventId)
   {
       if (_guests != null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot call {nameof(GetGuestsAtEvent)} more than once");

       _guests = new List<GuestInfo>();
       foreach (var result in _dataStore.GetEventAttendees(eventId))
       {
           if (result.IsGuest)
           {
             _guests.Add(new GuestInfo { GuestId = restult.GuestId, EmailAddress = result.EmailAddress });
           }
       }
   }

   public SendEmailToGuests(ITemplate emailTemplate)
   {
       if (_guests == null) throw new Exception($"{nameof(GetGuestsAtEvent)} must be called before {nameof(SendEmailToGuests)}");

       foreach (var guest in _guests)
       {
           var emailBody = template.Apply(guest.GuestId);
           _emailer.Send(emailBody, guest.EmailAddress);
       }
   }
}
```

This has several advantages. The class name describes what it does, whereas `HotelUtilities` doesn't, making single responsibility classes easier to understand. It's testable, use a mocking framework to create mocks of the interfaces it uses, and you can easily test the class's business logic, including edge cases and error cases. It encapsulates a unit of business logic, so if requirements change about who to email after an event, the class is easy to find because of a useful name, and the code is in one place, rather than getting the list of visitors in one place, building the email body from a template in another, and sending emails from a third place.

Basically, your question feels like a case of an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). You're working on something and encountered an issue, for which you're looking for a work-around. If you take a step back and look for different approaches, you may find a solution that doesn't require a work-around at all.